# How can I amend this code so that I don't have to sort an Object?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code/data to display a list of our top-earning students in each House.

---

**The data**

[image: User_Info is an array of Objects]
Attachment 1: User_Info is *an array of Objects*

[image: User_Info is an array of Objects such as this]
Attachment 2: User_Info is an array of *Objects such as this*

[image: Database_Info is an Object like this]
Attachment 3: Database_Info is *an Object* like this

---

**The code**

```
    HPAnalysisObject.dispHPTotals = function(User_Info, Database_Info) {
        // See attachments 1 and 2
        console.log(User_Info);
        // See attachment 3
        console.log(Database_Info);

        // "label" is just a text title, like "Eagles"
        var html = '<h2>' + HPAnalysisObject.label + '</h2>' + 
            // "TotalPoints" is an integer figure
            '<div id="total">' + Database_Info.TotalPoints + '</div>';

        // create the table to display
        html += '<table><tr><th class="name">Name</th><th class="points">Points</th></tr>';

        // use "for, in" to access the value of the object key (which is the user's ID)
        for (var id in Database_Info.UserDetails) {
            html += '<tr>';
            for (var i = 0; i < User_Info.length; i++) {
                if (User_Info[i].id == id) {
                    // if the User_Info and Database_Info objects match up on the User's ID, add table cells to our html variable
                    html += '<td class="name">' + User_Info[i].firstname + ' ' + User_Info[i].surname + '</td><td class="points">' + Database_Info.UserDetails[id] + '</td>';
                }
            }
            html += '</tr>';
        }

        html += '</table>';

        $('div#display').html(html);
    };
```

---

**The problem**

Oddly, in Firefox, these students display in the correct numerical order, as the students are received from my PHP script.

However, in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, they appear in a seemingly-random order!

My first thought was to order the object, but having read a few questions on here, it seems like ordering objects isn't the best practice.

*Can I rewrite this code so that I display the same tabular data - just in the right order on every browser?*

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most languages, you cannot assume that object attributes occur in any particular order.

One solution might be to add an accessor to each entry in UserDetails such as:

UserDetails={
  ID:{
    accessor:1,
    id: ID
  }
}

And then sort the records on UserDetails[ID].accessor.

Another might be to construct UserDetails as an array of elements which encode key values as "key:value", splitting each retrieved elements on /:/ as in:

[
  "90030:87"
  ...
]

EDIT

Assuming

```
var userDetails={
                  a:{i:3,key:'third'},
                  b:{i:1,key:'first'},
                  c:{i:2,key:'second'}
};
```

where i is the accessor, you can create a sorted array of objects using

```
var sortedObjs=Object.keys(userDetails)
                     .map(function(k){ return userDetails[k] })
                     .sort(function(left,right){ return left['i']-right['i'] });
```

which extracts keys from userDetails, creates an array of the keyed elements via map and sorts the resulting elements by their accessor value such that

```
console.log(sortedObjs.map(function(elt){return elt.key}).join(','))
```

will print to the console:

```
first,second,third
```

Comment: The accessor sounds like the best approach. How would I go about sorting the records from that key though? Would it be a simple `for` loop? I can't get my head round how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are an unsorted mapping of keys to values, their order is never guaranteed.

When I get anything like this, I like to build an array using the ID as numeric keys. For instance, something like this in PHP:

```
$out = Array();
while($row = database_get_row($set)) { // replace with your choice of database library
    $out[$row['id']] = $row;
}
ksort($out);
$out = array_values($out);
```

In this way, you can ensure that the array is in order of increasing ID, and then pass that array to JavaScript for use in a `for(i=0;i<l;i++)` loop.

Comment: Thanks for that Kolink. The `Database_Info` object is built from a PHP Script in which I utilise `arsort` to make sure the array is ordered correctly. However, the problem appears to lie with the `for in` loop in JavaScript; so ideally I'm looking to replace that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to sort Database_Info.UserDetails using an array wrapper:

```
// test data using same data as example but with no order
var Database_Info = { 
  UserDetails : { 
    137473 : 87, 
    90132 : 126, 
    90057 : 79, 
    90030 : 87, 
    90095 : 82 
  }
}

var objWrapper = [];
for (key in Database_Info.UserDetails) {
  objWrapper.push(key);
}
objWrapper.sort(); // default sort = numeric order ascending

for (a = 0, b = objWrapper.length; a < b; a++) {
  var userInfo = Database_Info.UserDetails[objWrapper[a]];
  // do something interesting
  console.log(userInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to wrap my Objects in a sortable array. This appeared to do the trick.

```
HPAnalysisObject.dispHPTotals = function(User_Info, Database_Info) {            
    // make a sortable array
    var Combined_Info = [];

    // "label" is just a text title, like "Eagles"
    var html = '<h2>' + HPAnalysisObject.label + '</h2>' + 
        // "TotalPoints" is an integer figure
        '<div id="total">' + Database_Info.TotalPoints + '</div>';

    // create the table to display
    html += '<table><tr><th class="name">Name</th><th class="points">Points</th></tr>';

    // use "for, in" to access the value of the object key (which is the user's ID)
    for (var id in Database_Info.UserDetails) {

        for (var i = 0; i < User_Info.length; i++) {
            if (User_Info[i].id == id) {
                var StudentInfo = { name: User_Info[i].firstname + ' ' + User_Info[i].surname, points: Database_Info.UserDetails[id] };
                Combined_Info.push(StudentInfo);
            }
        }

    }

    Combined_Info.sort( function(a, b) {
        return b.points - a.points;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < Combined_Info.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td class="name">' + Combined_Info[i].name + '</td><td class="points">' + Combined_Info[i].points + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    }

    html += '</table>';

    $('div#display').html(html);
};
```